# How to determine if a class implements != operator overloading?

Tags: c++

Given the following function:

```
template <typename T>
static bool equals(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b) {
  if (a.size() != b.size())
    return false;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    if (a[i] != b[i]) // Requires that the != operator is supported by the template type.
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

how can I determine if the given T overrides the `!=` operator? If someone uses a type without overloading it might end up using a simple binary comparison which might silently lead to wrong results. So I want to ensure only classes that have their own `!=` operator overloading can be used here.

Comment: sorry, I dont understand, If the type does not have a `!=` the template wont get instantiated, if it has it, then everything should be fine, no?

Comment: I am not sure you can do this as built in types do not have member functions(which marcinj just proved me wonrg).  Personally instead of trying to figure this out I would do what the standard does and add an overload that takes a comparison object and uses that.  If the types provide built in operators the user can use the first version., otherwise they can use the overload and supply a comparator.  You could also just use [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal)

Comment: @tobi303 I think the OP is worried that the type could have a conversion operator that the elements could convert to and then that is compared.  I don't think the language allows that and if that is the case then you are correct that this is not needed.

Comment: Good points! Yes, I'm worried that the != comparison uses a default implementation without letting me know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the title of my question here says I'm looking for a way to determine if the != operator is defined, the real question (as you can read from the description and my comment) was how to ensure that I don't silently get wrong results for a type T which has no != operator defined. The existing answers brought up good points, but the real answer is this:

1) You will get a compiler error on the `if (a[i] != b[i])` line if you instantiate the template with a value type array using a type that's missing the `!=` operator override (e.g. `std::vector<sample2>` from marcinj's answer) or you get hard to understand compiler error if you use `std::equal` instead. In this case the explicit comparison is much more helpful when looking for a solution.

2) If you have a reference type in the vectors to compare you will at first get no problem at all (since there are comparison operators defined for references, even though they only do a flat comparison via the address values). If you want to ensure that the comparison works as if you had used value types (including deep comparison) then add a specialization for vectors with pointer types, as pointed out by Pixelchemist. However, I cannot get the std::equals variants to compile at the moment.

At the end the solution that works for me is this:

```
template <typename T>
static bool equals(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b) {
  if (a.size() != b.size())
    return false;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    if (a[i] != b[i])
      return false;

  return true;
}

template <typename T>
static bool equals(const std::vector<T*> &a, const std::vector<T*> &b) {
  if (a.size() != b.size())
    return false;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    if (*a[i] != *b[i])
      return false;

  return true;
}
```

Tested with the sample1/2/3/4 structs from marcinj's answer. It's important to note that the operator overloading must use a value type (`operator == (const sample1&)`) instead of a reference type.

I have still upvoted all answers that gave me useful information to get the final answer.

Answer (score 5):

[update 1 - boost 'semi' solution]

I realized that example from my first answer does not work if your class has conversion operator (to type which allows for != comparision), to fix it you can use boost [has_not_equal_to](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/type_traits/doc/html/boost_typetraits/reference/has_not_equal_to.html) type trait. Still its not perfect, as in some cases it generates compilation error instead of giving a value. Those cases are listed in provided link.

[update 2 - concepts solution]

Example with use of concepts:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
concept bool OperatorNotEqual_comparable()
{
    return requires (T a, T b) {
        { a.operator!=(b) } -> bool;
    };   
}

template <OperatorNotEqual_comparable T>
static bool equals(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b) {
  if (a.size() != b.size())
    return false;

  for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
    if (a[i] != b[i]) // Requires that the != operator is supported by the template type.
      return false;

  return true;
}

struct sample1{
    bool operator!=(const sample1&) const { return true; }
};

struct sample2{
};

struct sample3{
    operator void*() { return 0; }
};

int main() {
    // Compiles ok!
    std::vector<sample1> vec1;
    equals(vec1, vec1);

    // Fails, which is OK!
    //std::vector<sample2> vec2;
    //equals(vec2, vec2);    

    // Fails, which is OK!
    //std::vector<sample2*> vec2;
    //equals(vec2, vec2);

    // Fails, which is OK!
    //std::vector<int> vec4;
    //equals(vec4, vec4);        

    // Fails, which is OK!
    //std::vector<sample3> vec5;
    //equals(vec5, vec5);            
}
```

http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/txliKPeMcStc6FhK

[old answer - SFINAE solution, does not check for conversion operator]

You can use SFINAE, and in the near future concepts (they are in gcc 6.0),

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
class has_not_equal{
    template<typename U>
    struct null_value{
        static U& value;
    };

    template<typename U>
    static std::true_type test(U*,decltype(null_value<U>::value!=null_value<U>::value)* = 0);
    static std::false_type test(void*);

public:
    typedef decltype(test(static_cast<T*>(0))) type;
    static const bool value = type::value;
};

struct sample1{
    bool operator!=(const sample1&) { return true; }
};

struct sample2{
};

int main(){
    std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<int>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<std::string>::value<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<has_not_equal<sample1>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<sample2>::value<<std::endl;
}
```

output:

```
g++ -std=c++14 -O2 -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out
true
true
true
false
```

[live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c9064ce77ea61e10)

above code is a modified version from this [site](http://dixq.net/forum/blog.php?u=673&b=2137), it was for `operator==`, I changed it to `operator!=`

Comment: I dont understand, how this helps. Anyhow if `T` has no `!=` operator, the OPs `equals<T>` wont compile, or am i missing something?

Comment: I agree, I suppose with static assertion it is possible to give some better information of the error. The whole Concepts idea is to give better error messages - shorter and more meaningfull.

Comment: While this works nicely for value types it does not for pointer types. For instance `std::cout<<has_not_equal<sample2*>::value<<std::endl;` will print `true`.

Comment: @MikeLischke you might check if T is of class type, also disallow pointers -   those checks are provided by boost type traits also I suppose C++11 also has them. I have updated answer with Concepts solution which is the most elegant.

Answer (score 1):

If `T` has no `operator !=`, then the template wont get instantiated for that type, but you will get a (possibly horribly long and unreadable) error message from your compiler. On the other hand, it `T` has a `operator !=`, then it should be just fine to use it. There wont be silent wrong result, unless `T`s `operator !=` is anyhow broken.

Answer (score 1):

The only other (besides the conversion) case (I can think of) where a binary comparison can happen (has `operator!=` defined) and lead to silently wrong results is when `T` is actually a pointer and you expect a "deep comparison".

One could add an overload for vectors containg pointers but that wouldn't cover pointer to array storage.

```
template <typename T>
static bool equals(const std::vector<T> &a, const std::vector<T> &b) 
{
  return std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin());
}

template <typename T>
static bool equals(const std::vector<T *> &a, const std::vector<T *> &b) 
{
  return std::equal(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin() 
    [](T* ap, T* bp) -> bool { return *ap == *bp; });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in check whether there is an operator != defined in a class (and it has precisely given signature) you may want this approach (tests taken from marcinj's code):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T, class = void>
struct has_not_equal: std::false_type { };

template <class T>
struct has_not_equal<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<decltype(static_cast<bool (T::*)(const T&)const>(&T::operator!=)), bool (T::*)(const T&)const>::value>::type >: std::true_type { };

struct sample1{
    bool operator!=(const sample1&) const { return true; }
};
struct sample2{
};
struct sample3:sample2 {
  bool operator!=(const sample2& b) const { return true; }
};

struct sample4:sample2 {
  bool operator!=(const sample2& b) const { return true; }
  bool operator!=(const sample4& b) const { return true; }
};

int main(){

    std::cout<<std::boolalpha;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<int>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<std::string>::value<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<has_not_equal<sample1>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<sample2>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<sample3>::value<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<has_not_equal<sample4>::value<<std::endl;
}
```

Output of the program:

```
false
false
true
false
false
true
```

You may easily add allowed operator != overloads by adding specialization of the has_not_equal struct...

Answer (score 0):

> If someone uses a type without overloading it might end up using a simple binary comparison which might silently lead to wrong results.

There's not such thing as "binary comparison" in C++. Either your class/struct has `operator!=` or the template won't be instantiated (and if there are no other candidates then it will be an error).